# How to define a new optimization function for Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, keras

I would like to implement for Keras a new optimization function that would not be based on the partial derivatives of the parameters, but also on the derivatives of these partial derivatives. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You start by creating a custom optimizer by looking at the [code for the current optimizers](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py).

You can see that an optimizer can be defined by subclassing `keras.optimizers.Optimizer`:

```py
from keras.optimizers import Optimizer

class CustomOptimizer(Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, custom, parameters, **kwargs):
        self.custom = custom
        self.parameters = parameters
        # ...
        super().__init__(kwargs)

    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        # calculate the updates for the parameters
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)  # as implemented in `Optimizer`
        # ...
        self.updates = # your updates
        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        return {'custom': custom, 'parameters': parameters}
```

Here I believe you can calculate the derivative of the gradients in `get_updates()` in the same way as `get_gradients()` is implemented (take a look at Keras' code).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, after having looked at the Keras code of the Optimizer 2-3 times, not only did I quickly give up trying to understand everything, but it seemed to me that the get_updates function simply returns the gradients already calculated, where I seek to directly access the partial derivation functions of the parameters in order to use the derivatives of these derivatives. So the gradients are useless ...